# Streaming data using BLE L2CAP(LE Credit based flow control mode) is not working in background

Tags: ios, swift3

I am trying to stream data from Peripheral device to iPhone using L2CAP. I am able to receive data continuously in the foreground mode, but when the app goes to background mode, not able to receive data . Have enabled required capabilities for background mode i.e., uses bluetooth LE accessories.

Please let me know how to support streaming in background mode?